# Is it OK to ask questions in solid mechanics

Tags: support, allowed-questions

As the title says: Is it OK to ask solid mechanics questions in MSE. I know that my questions may belong somewhere else. The reason I want to ask my questions here is because I want rigorous answers that use formal definitions. I believe the best place to acheive this is here.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I firmly believe that questions should be asked where they will receive the best answers. I don't know if your question fits better here or at physics.se, but I recommend that you try it at one of the two and see if it works. If it doesn't, then we can migrate it to the other.

Comment: I think my questions in this area should be classified as applied math. However I don't see an applied math tag

Comment: I believe the answer that I am looking for will come from an applied mathematician and most probably from nobody else (I already tried asking non-applied mathematicians doctors in my uni)

Comment: @Amr I guess `classical-mechanics` is the closest existing tag. There is also `applications`. // Someone (Arnold?) said, "there is no applied mathematics; there are applications of mathematics".

Comment: @5PM I will try this

Comment: There's also just the `physics` tag. @Amr what do you mean by "solid mechanics"?

Comment: @WillieWong Maybe this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_mechanics